# Adding images to the user bundle which is in resources folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I implemented the concept adding images to the main bundle.I unaware of that how to add images  to the user(user created bundle) bundle which is in resources folder.If any one knows,suggest me to achieve it.
                                    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't *support files* automatically get copied to the `Resources` folder by Xcode?  There is a build step that shows what files will be copied once you have added the files to your project.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is asking.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add a particular image on to the user bundle.I mean syntax like that

Comment: In Xcode: `Project > Add to Project`.

Comment: I am having one image,the image is displaying in imageview(xib),when i build the app at that time the image has to store in user created bundle

Comment: You can't add any thing to the user bundle at runtime and May use Applicationdirectory, Refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673389/iphone-how-to-store-images-in-directory-structure-vs-flat-documents-directory